# A simple c++11 macro

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I'm trying to construct a simple c++ macro and I cannot even get started.  Google hasn't helped so far.

```
#define blow (...) __VA_ARGS__
int main () {
    blow();
    }
```

Produces these errors:

```
g++ -fpermissive -std=gnu++11 -g3 -I/eclipse/workspace/shared /eclipse/workspace/shared/amanda.c++ -o /binaries/amanda
[g++ shared/amanda took 0.0 seconds]
 1. /eclipse/workspace/shared/amanda.c++:7:20: warning: __VA_ARGS__ can only appear in the expansion of a C99 variadic macro [enabled by default]
 2.  #define blow (...) __VA_ARGS__
 3.                     ^
 4. /eclipse/workspace/shared/amanda.c++: In function ‘int main()’:
 5. /eclipse/workspace/shared/amanda.c++:7:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token
 6.  #define blow (...) __VA_ARGS__
 7.                ^
 8. /eclipse/workspace/shared/amanda.c++:9:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘blow’
 9.   blow();
10.   ^
11. /eclipse/workspace/shared/amanda.c++:7:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘...’ token
12.  #define blow (...) __VA_ARGS__
13.                ^
14. /eclipse/workspace/shared/amanda.c++:9:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘blow’
15.   blow();
16.   ^
```

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: I've been through the Variadic-Macros document.  The difference is that I want to allow for no values rather that requiring an initial "format" field.

Comment: If your goal is to construct a simple macro, then don't try to create a variadic macro, since those are less simple than non-variadic.

Comment: It will be a simple macro that feeds a variadic macro.

Comment: What I am hoping for is an understanding of the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The macro definition should be without spaces between the macro name and `(`:

```
#define blow(...) __VA_ARGS__
int main () {
    blow();
}
```

With space, you define the normal non-variadic macro `blow` which expands to `(...) __VA_ARGS__`, which causes your error messages.